# How to install DFSN module in powershell?

Tags: powershell, dfs, powershell-v5.0

I have two machines, one has DFSN available (functions like Get-DfsnFolderTarget, etc) and the other doesn't.

I can't seem to find any information online about installing it, and I'm not a powershell expoert. I found references to the powerhsell command Install-Module, but running `Install-Module DFSN` gives the error `No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'DFSN'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.`

I can't find a manual install anywhere.

The system that has it is Windows 10 Pro 1903 Build 18362, and the one that is missing the module is newer - Windows 10 Pro 20H2 Build 19042

Comment: [Install DFS Namespace, DFS Replication, and the related management tools](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/windows-server-2016/9781787122048/91674ff4-3f5c-4c62-8cd1-2c6c44596f87.xhtml)?

Comment: This page didn't work for me directly, but it did lead me down a path that eventually go me there! unfortunately, all of the commands on this webpage appear to only work on windows servers, not windows 10 pro. Searching start menu for Optional Features -> Add a Feature -> Installing "RSAT: File Services Tools" added the command I was looking for into powershell.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can't install this through powershell directly, but rather it's an "Optional windows feature" you have to enable.

The fix for me was going to the start menu and searching for "Manage optional features", clicking "Add a feature", and installing "RSAT: File Services Tools".

After that, all of the DFSN and DFSR commands started working in powershell.